# Highlight word and delete from CMD?

Tags: git, command-prompt, git-bash

Oftentimes, I really need to select text by simply highlighting it with a cursor and pressing delete. While I do need to get used to using `Ctrl+Backspace` to delete words the cursor is in front of, I've changed my command prompt to function like normal text in pretty much every aspect but this, and have never used this shortcut once in my life anyway. Is this possible? (I am using Git-Bash for Windows)

Comment: Are you talking about *command line* editor? In Unix it's `readline` library which does provide editor in the shell and it has tons of (useful) short cuts.

Comment: No, I mean the command being typed out  itself. I can't count how often I've type `sample text blah blah`, double-clicked blah, pressed backspace, and nothing has happened.

Comment: What do you mean _nothing_? BTW, _Ctrl + w_  does something?

Comment: You are a legend. Thank you. Why did I not see that, I even looked in my ~/.inputrc file.

Comment: Yep, _.inputrc_ **is** a configuration file of _readline_ in shell. I have answer on ruSO about similar matters, but afraid you may not understand it w/o translation. So, if you wish to credit me, vote up this https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/764761/180002

Comment: It's auto-translated in chrome :) Спасибо, but Idon't have 15 rep anyways :/